# MYSQL Join Query Optimization with Multiple tablesU

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables

Class,Exam,Questions,Answers,UserResponses

```
Class -> ID , Name
Exam -> ID,Name,Class_ID_FK
Questions -> ID,Question,Exam_ID,FK
Answers -> ID,Answer,Question_ID_Fk
UserResponses -> ID,UserID,Answer_ID_fk,Question_ID_fk
```

I want to fetch all user reposes for all exams of given class.I have written up a query but I want to see what other people suggest and if I am going in right direction since 500 instances of this query might be running in my system at same time.

```
select r.answer_id_fk,r.userid,q.question,a.answer,e.name,e.class_id_fk
from  Exams e 
join Questions q on q.exam_id_fk = e.id  
join Answers a on a.question_id_fk = q.id 
left join UserResponses r on r.answer_id_fk = a.id
where  e.class_id_fk =105585;
```

I think this ends up going through all rows in database which might end up crashing .

Explain shows this. It returns 35 rows which is correct .I have 18091 rows in question tables.20423 in responses.And '67108' in answers.

```
1, SIMPLE, a, ALL, , , , , 67108, 
1, SIMPLE, q, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 25, db_qa_dev.a.question_id_fk, 1, 
1, SIMPLE, c, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 25, db_qa_dev.q.category_id_fk, 1, Using where
1, SIMPLE, r, ref, ANSWERID_INDEX, ANSWERID_INDEX, 26, db_qa_dev.a.id, 15, Using index
```

Comment: This isn't rent-a-coder -- show you've done some work.

Comment: How about posting your query? Then we could suggest more things about it.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Posted query

Comment: And what does an EXPLAIN on the query show?

Comment: Do you have an index on the `class_id_fk` column in the `Exam` table? Is that very selective or does your data in the `Exam` table mostly apply to the same `Class` so far?

Comment: @Tom H.  Yes its selective . Yes its indexed.

Comment: Can I further assume that you have indexes on all of the FKs? For example, q.exam_id_fk. It seems odd that MySQL would pick that particular execution plan for that query. Does MySQL have an equivalent to MS SQL's plan cache? Could this need to be cleared?

Comment: @Tom H.  Yes I have indexes on all those FK .No, There is no plan cached .

Comment: You explain output does not match the query, the aliases do not match, please post the correct query and matching explain.

Comment: @Tom H You were right  I was missing one index on UserResponse table . That fixed it ! May be you can add that as an answer . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that the explain plan is coming out, it looks like one of your foreign key indexes is missing. The MySQL engine should look for the optimum query plan, which often means starting with the most filtered data on an index and working from there. I don't know how the actual data looks, but I would guess that the constraint on `e.class_id_fk` should be pretty restrictive, so the engine would probably start by filtering down those rows. Then, since your `JOIN`s all involve simple FK/PK relationships it would just join in those single rows from the other tables.

The only reasons that I can think of for why it might not do this is because the data in one of your tables is really screwy (for example, every row in `Exam` has the same `class_id_fk` value) or you're missing an index on one of your FK columns.

Missing an index on an FK column might make the optimizer decide that it's faster to go a different route than to have to scan that table for every `JOIN`. In most scenarios you always want an index on all of your FKs because you will tend to `JOIN` on those columns a lot, so the index is very useful for reads.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explaination . This link might help someone . http://hackmysql.com/case4

Answer (score 1):

If you force a straight_join on the table with the least matches, your query should go much faster.
Note that you can only use straight_join to replace an inner join, because left join does not reduce the number of rows in the resultset.

Not 100% sure, because your explain select does not match your query.

```
SELECT r.answer_id_fk,r.userid,q.question,a.answer,e.name,e.class_id_fk
FROM Exams e 
STRAIGHT_JOIN Questions q ON (e.class_id_fk = '105585' AND q.exam_id_fk = e.id)  
STRAIGHT_JOIN Answers a on a.question_id_fk = q.id 
LEFT JOIN UserResponses r on r.answer_id_fk = a.id
```

Comment: I tried STRAIGHT_JOIN and show that it can optimize query and some other way. I used it after adding index without strait join and it worked fine but with it it simply ignored my indexes .